# codeigniter - Selecting data from database

Tags: php, codeigniter

Sorry for the basic question, but I couldn't fidn the answer anywhere online. I started with codeigniter yesterday And all I am trying to do is selecting data from my database. However I don't get any errors nor does it show any data. If i change the database tabel name. It immediately throws an error.

Model

```
<?php

    class Customer_model extends CI_Model {

        public function get_customers($id) {
            if ($id != FALSE) {
                $query = $this->db->get_where('customer', array('id' => $id));
            } else {
                return FALSE;
            }
        }

    }
```

Controller

```
<?php

    class Customer extends CI_Controller {

        public function show($id) {
            $this->load->model('customer_model');
            $news = $this->customer_model->get_customers($id);

            $data['customer_name'] = $news['customer_name'];
            $data['streetname'] = $news['streetname'];
            $this->load->view('customers', $data);
        }

    }
```

VIEW

```
<?php echo "hallo"; ?>
<?php echo $customer_name; ?>
```

** EDIT, in my page is can see the echo of hello. So I am in the correct page, but there are no errors nor notices of any data missing.

If anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong, thanks a zillion. btw database connectivity is included and also the package is loaded.

thanks

Comment: N.B.: When pasting code, highlight the code and hit CTRL-K or the `{}` and that will indent your code. I had to edit your question.

Comment: *"It immediately throws an error"* - Being what *exactly?*

Comment: ah I was wondering how to do that, thanks

Comment: Well no return of `query result`!! You just `return false` when `$id != FALSE`!!

Comment: You're welcome. Are you using CI's Error Handler? https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/errors.html

Comment: Read Generating Query Results http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html?highlight=fetch

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**In Model**

```
class Customer_model extends CI_Model {

    public function get_customers($id) { # refactored 

        $this->db->select(*);            
        $query = $this->db->get_where('customer', array('id' => $id));
        $result = $query->result_array();

        $count = count($result); 

        if(empty($count)){
            return false;
        }
        else{
            return $result;
        }
    }
}
```

**In Controller**

```
class Customer extends CI_Controller {

    public function show($id) {

        if(empty($id)) # Added
        { 
            echo "Token Invalid";
        }
        else{
            $this->load->model('customer_model');
            $news = $this->customer_model->get_customers($id);

            if($news == false){ # Added
                echo "No result Found";
            }
            else{
                $data['customer_name'] = $news[0]['customer_name']; # Changed
                $data['streetname'] = $news[0]['streetname']; # Changed
                $this->load->view('customers', $data);              
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the solution!! but little explanation make it better!!

Comment: Worked like a charm. i was missing some important concepts of the framework, like explicity loading the model class and returning it's value to the controller. Thanks for clearing it up mate.